# Using mathematical operators in multi variable parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, mathematical-optimization

I'm wondering if it's possible to include mathematical operators and situations in a multivariable parameter.

In my example, I'm looking to have the freedom to enter 'Overdue' 'Less than one day' or 'More than one day' as @SLA_Days.

Currently, I can enter any of these one variables and it will return a result.

```
if @sla_days = 'Overdue'
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and sla_days < 0' 
    END
ELSE

if @sla_days = 'Less than one day'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and sla_days <1 and sla_days >0'
    END
ELSE

if @sla_days = 'More than one day'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = @sql + 'and sla_days > 1'
    END

EXEC sp_exectuesql @SQL
```

I do have a function that I've created that will look a comma delimited string and pull out variables. I do not need help in creating this

What I do need help is, is it possible to enter @SLA_days = 'Overdue,Less than one day,More than one day' and still have it recognize these rules?

Therefore, if I selected Overdue and less than one day, it would return both values where sla_days < 0 and sla days < 1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function to pull out variables. This will perform much better.

The trick for your specific problem is to use `OR` instead of `AND`, because the value in a column could never be, for example, `> 0` AND `< 0`. Also I add commas to each side of the variable so that conditions can be identified in any order. Note, though, that it will not find values if there are spaces between the commas as well - you'll have to adjust for that.

```
SET @SLA_days = ',' + @SLA_days + ',';

SET @sql = @sql + ' (1=2 '
  + CASE WHEN @SLA_days LIKE '%,Overdue,%'
    THEN ' OR (sla_days < 0)' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @SLA_days LIKE '%,Less than one day,%'
    THEN ' OR (sla_days < 1 AND sla_days > 0)' ELSE '' END
  + CASE WHEN @SLA_days LIKE '%,More than one day,%'
    THEN ' OR (sla_days > 1)' ELSE '' END + ')';
```

Finally, do you *really* need to pass these big ugly strings to the database? Presumably the users are selecting from a multi-select or checking boxes, in which case you could use much tidier coefficients to represent each case.

Comment: I could most certainly replace my strings with 1, 2, and 3 to make it easier. By doing that, would it change my script at all?

Comment: @user2191477 not really, you would still have to do conditionals to create the right `WHERE` clause, unless your coefficients actually were ranges. For example, you could pass in the actual clause(s) to append, or you could pass in multiple values and do > and < for each clause. Seems unnecessary to change if what you have works and isn't going to get much more complex.